# Having trouble finding examples of sets of functions that do NOT form a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534085/show-that-the-set-of-all-functions-described-by-yt-c-1-cos-omega-t-c-2-si?rq=1) someone asks about showing that the set of all functions of the form $y(t) = c_1\cos\omega t + c_2\sin\omega t$ is a vector space. But doesn't literally any set of functions of the form $y(t) = c_1f(t) + c_2g(t) + \ldots$ form a vector space? After all, there will always be a zero element (coefficients = 0) and an additive inverse (coefficients of opposite sign), and trivially scaling or adding two $y(t)$ will yield another function of the same form.

So what is an example of a set of functions that do NOT form a vector space? The most common pedagogic example I've seen is unsatisfyingly contrived: the set of all polynomials of degree N. This is explained to not form a vector space because the zero element is not of degree N. However technically the zero element is still of the form $c_1 + c_2x + \ldots + c_Nx^N$, so I'm not sure how comfortable I am with this example.

Comment: The space of all constant functions except $f(x)=3$.  The space of all functions such that $F(0)=1$. The space of all polynomials of degree exactly $2$.  The space of all polynomials with lead coefficient $1$.   And so on.

Comment: Yes, the set of all finite linear combinations of any set of complex- (or real-)valued functions on some domain forms a vector space.  That's still a very special set of functions.  How about the set of discontinuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$?  That's not a vector space.

Comment: Take any set of functions and remove zero (given it's in the set).

Comment: @saulspatz, isn't not allowing functions to be continuous a more special set of functions than just the set of complex/real valued functions?

Comment: Yes.  Any set of functions is more special than the set of all functions.  So what?

Comment: @amsmath, but why would you remove zero? Can anyone come up with examples that don't seem so contrived? Context: I'm a physicist (*ducks head*), and would like to be able to explain why students should be worried about vector spaces if every ordinary function they can think of forms a vector space. Boundary conditions with functions having to be zero is well-motivated, but (unlike the f(0)=1 example), I don't see how this can lead to linear combinations falling outside the space, since 0+0 is still 0.

Comment: @saulspatz, you seemed to be implying that my example was special and that by loosening assumptions would lead to functions no longer being a vector space, but maybe I misunderstood your point about what a "special" set of functions the set of all functions is.

Comment: @user1247 How contrived something is is subjective. What about the set of strictly increasing functions? Is that contrived or not?

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding one another.  When you said that "doesn't literally any set of functions of...form a vector space," it sounded to me like you were saying that we should expect an arbitrary set of functions to have this property, and I was saying, "No, this is a very special property."  (In fact, it's a vector space of functions).  As for discontinuous functions, I was just giving what seemed to me a natural, uncontrived example of a set of functions that don't form a vector space.

Comment: @79037662, maybe so -- I like your example and think it is less contrived (to my taste) than the others

Comment: @user1247 Here are a few more I hope you find not contrived: set of positive everywhere functions, set of monotone functions, set of non-differentiable functions, set of unbounded functions. Also in general, for any property that the zero function *doesn't* have, the set of functions *with* that property will not be a vector space. (This is similar to what amsmath said.)

Answer (score 2):

Take your favourite differential equation, as long as it's not a homogeneous linear one. Then its solution set isn't a vector space under the usual definitions for functions of scaling and addition. Surely that's not a contrived example.

For the sake of physical examples, note that the linearity of quantum mechanics and electromagnetism is starkly at odds with the nonlinearity of general relativity and nuclear interactions. The Higgs field satisfies a nonlinear differential equation. While electromagnetism is linear, it's inhomogeneous with a source. [Fluid mechanics is nonlinear too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field).

Comment: Do you mean that the solution set considered as functions separately from the DE do not constitute a vector space, or do you mean that linear combinations of solutions do not anymore satisfy the DE. The latter is obvious to me, but the former is not. Can you provide an example set of several functions that are not a vector space?

Comment: @user1247 The statements are equivalent. For example, consider $y^\prime=-y^2$; the solutions are $y=1/(x+c)$.

Comment: The space of functions being considered would be indexed as $(c_1,c_2,\ldots)$ meaning $1/(x+c_1)$,  $1/(x+c_2)$, ...? Just making sure I understand -- we are not talking about linear combinations where the $c_n$ are the coefficients in front of each solution?

Comment: @user1247 Compare that to solutions of an inhomogeneous wave equation, which are far too general to give a similar treatment.

Comment: Thanks -- but doesn't any situation in which you don't allow the multiplicative coefficient to vary, almost trivially (by definition) not form a vector space? Or am I not imaginative enough -- are there examples similar to your non-example?

Comment: I think I thought of an example: functions of the form ln(x^c) seem to satisfy the properties of a vector space

Comment: @user1247 But we're looking for *counter*examples.

Comment: Did you see my previous question that you didn't respond to? You may have missed it. Here it is again: "Thanks -- but doesn't any situation in which you don't allow the multiplicative coefficient to vary, almost trivially (by definition) not form a vector space? Or am I not imaginative enough -- are there examples similar to your non-example?" Thanks

Comment: @user1247 I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: The class of functions of the form $ln(x^c)$ have the curious property that $ln(x^c_1)+ln(x^c_2)=ln(x^{c_1+c_2})=ln(x^c_3)$ and $A ln(x^c)=ln(x^{A c})=ln(x^d)$, and so form a vector space (c=0 gives the zero, and 1/c gives the additive inverse). So this shows that your non-example is not trivially true by virtue of defining your class of functions to not include multiplicative factors of those functions. In other words I like your example, thanks.

Comment: @user1247 You realise it's just $c\ln x$, right?

Comment: I do! But this is part of my confusion. For example the most common example I see in textbooks is: the set of polynomials of order N. This is said to not be a vector space because if we add two polynomials of order N together we can get a polynomial that is not of order N. But I want to respond "you do realize" that a polynomial that is "not of order N" is the same as a polynomial of order N where the coefficient in front of $x^N$ is zero! So it seems like our definition of what counts as one of our functions is artificially contrived to only include specific notations.

Comment: And I'm left wondering again, the question I asked earlier "but doesn't any situation in which you don't allow the multiplicative coefficient to vary, almost trivially (by definition) not form a vector space?" Perhaps the only cases that *do* form a vector space do so by leveraging an arguably notational equality like $c ln x = ln x^c$

Comment: @user1247 The point with polynomials is we want each polynomial to have a unique well-defined degree, namely the least one that works, which will always be of a term of non-vanishing coefficient. On the other hand, the polynomials of degree $\le n$ comprise a vector space.

Comment: Right, and that is consistent with my thought: if you deny that multiplicative scalings of your functions (such as scaling by zero in the above case) are in your space of functions, then isn't it trivially true that the functions cannot form a vector space? The $ln(x^c)$ example was meant to show perhaps not, but as you point out this is "smuggling in scaling" through an identity. But I think that any example is going to be like that.

Comment: @user1247 I think the issue is with how you posed your question. Its title asked for something with countless examples; its first paragraph asked for the impossible - a set with an explicit vector-space basis that isn't a basis; it second paragraph basically returned to the title question, but with the vague addition that non-space sets of functions not feel "contrived". Maybe you think any set not provided a closure-under-linear-combinations rule is "contrived", no matter how natural or important it may be.